# extract all values of postgresql jsonb object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

i have a postgresql table t1 , id integer , data jsonb

```
   id    |   data
--------------------
    1    | {"1":{"11":11},"2":{"12":12}}
```

and i need a function to extract all key/value in separate rows 
like this

```
   key   |   values
----------------------
    1    |  {"11":11}
    2    |  {"12":12}
```

in "hstore" dataType , there was "hvals" function , do this 
 
but in jsonb i dont find similar function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [`jsonb_each`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
with t1 (id, data) as (
  values (1, '{"1":{"11":11},"2":{"12":12}}'::jsonb)
)
select t.*
from t1, jsonb_each(data) as t(k,v)
```

returns:

```
k | v         
--+-----------
1 | {"11": 11}
2 | {"12": 12}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a specific key's value instead of the entire JSON under the v column?